# rename internal name of document library

Tags: 2013, document-library, powershell

I would like to know if it is possible to change the internal name of a document library using something like powershell?

Comment: Does it have to be via PowerShell? You could do it manually with SharePoint Designer. Click on 'All Files' on the left hand site, search for the library, then right-click it and rename it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The InternalName is immutable. It cannot be changed once it has been established.

Answer (score 0):

If you have alternative of PowerShell then SharePoint Designer can do that.
See the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904944/change-sharepoint-library-url) asked by another user and refer answer which is marked as answer which uses SharePoint Designer for it.

> In SharePoint Designer just navigate to All Files navigation node (not List and Libraries node), find your document library there -> right-click library -> rename.